# Very slow boot after installing Kali Linux along with Ubuntu & Windows

Tags: ubuntu, boot, kali-linux, dual-boot, swap

What made Ubuntu boot very slow after Kali installation? it's taking a lot of time now and booting now shows a black screen for about 1 minute before showing the Ubuntu logo.
Before installing Kali in `dev/sda10` Ubuntu was booting very fast from `dev/sda8`.

I have reinstalled grub booter again and made it the old Ubuntu default grub booter after Kali used it's default grub booter & theme, and the problem still persists.

Here is the boot log :

```
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-ifup.slice.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sound Card.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-systemd\x2drfkill.slice.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Braille Device Support.
         Starting Braille Device Support...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization.
         Starting File System Check on Root Device...
         Starting Copy rules generated while the root was ro...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Copy rules generated while the root was ro.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
         Starting File System Check Daemon to report status...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started File System Check on Root Device.
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill1...
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0...
         Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:toshiba...
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0...
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0...
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting LSB: AppArmor initialization...
         Starting Set console keymap...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting Wait for all "auto" /etc/network/interfaces to be up for network-online.target...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Remote File Systems.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:toshiba.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill1.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Wait for all "auto" /etc/network/interfaces to be up for network-online.target.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Set console keymap.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: AppArmor initialization.
         Starting LSB: Raise network interfaces....
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started ifup for wlan0.
         Starting ifup for wlan0...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started ifup for eth0.
         Starting ifup for eth0...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Raise network interfaces..
[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (38s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (38s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (39s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[31m*     [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (39s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (40s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (40s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (41s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (41s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (42s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (42s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (43s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (43s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (44s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (44s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (45s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (45s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (46s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[31m*     [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (46s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (47s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (47s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (48s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (48s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (49s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (49s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (50s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (50s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (51s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (51s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (52s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (52s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (53s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[31m*     [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (53s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (54s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (54s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (55s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (55s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (56s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (56s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (57s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (57s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (58s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (58s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (59s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (59s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[31m*     [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 1s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 1s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 2s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 2s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 3s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 3s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 4s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 4s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 5s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 5s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 6s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 6s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 7s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[31m*     [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 7s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 8s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 8s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 9s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 9s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 10s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 10s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 11s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 11s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 12s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 12s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 13s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 13s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 14s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[31m*     [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 14s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 15s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 15s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 16s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 16s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 17s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 17s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 18s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 18s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 19s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 19s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 20s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 20s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 21s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[31m*     [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 21s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 22s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 22s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 23s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 23s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 24s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 24s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 25s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 25s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 26s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m* [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 26s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*  [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 27s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 27s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 28s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[31m*     [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 28s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m*[0m[31m*    [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 29s / 1min 30s)
[K[[31m*[1;31m*[0m[31m*   [0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device (1min 29s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m TIME [0m] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49d94255\x2d75f1\x2d494f\x2d8697\x2d3e64bb329913.device.
[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/49d94255-75f1-494f-8697-3e64bb329913.
[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Swap.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Initialization.
         Starting Restore Sound Card State...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Paths.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sockets.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started CUPS Scheduler.
         Starting CUPS Scheduler...
         Starting Bluetooth service...
         Starting LSB: Speech Dispatcher...
         Starting Modem Manager...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Cgroup management daemon.
         Starting Cgroup management daemon...
         Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
         Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
         Starting Enable support for additional executable binary formats...
         Starting Accounts Service...
         Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down....
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Run anacron jobs.
         Starting Run anacron jobs...
         Starting LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems...
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started crash report submission daemon.
         Starting crash report submission daemon...
         Starting LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"...
         Starting Network Manager...
         Starting LSB: start and stop timidity...
         Starting System Logging Service...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
         Starting Regular background program processing daemon...
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
         Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
         Starting Login Service...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Restore Sound Card State.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Permit User Sessions.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down..
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand".
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
         Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
         Starting Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Login Service.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Enable support for additional executable binary formats.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Bluetooth service.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Bluetooth.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started System Logging Service.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
         Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Thermal Daemon Service.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Accounts Service.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Modem Manager.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: start and stop timidity.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Manager.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
         Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
         Starting MySQL Community Server...
         Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
         Starting Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit...
         Starting WPA supplicant...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started WPA supplicant.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started MySQL Community Server.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
         Starting Light Display Manager...
```

#### Question:

Why Ubuntu booting is taking a lot of time since the Kali Linux installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was because Kali used Ubuntu's SWAP
[image: Linux SWAP and other partitions]

The solution is either to **make a new SWAP for Ubuntu** so that you have in total 2 SWAP memories, one for Kali and the other one for Ubuntu... Read more about [How to add SWAP partition after system installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation)

or you can **share the SWAP for both operating systems**, yes it's possible, the only downside is that you can't hibernate in a shared SWAP system. 
Read: [How to share SWAP between Kali and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735755/sharing-swap-and-home-beteween-ubuntu-15-10-and-kali-linux-2-0) for more info.